# Test for NULL value in a variable that may not be set

Tags: php

Considering that:

- The [isset()](http://es.php.net/isset) construct returns TRUE if a variable is set and not NULL
- The [is_null()](http://es.php.net/is_null) function throws a warning if the variable is not set

Is there a way to test whether a variable exists, no matter it's NULL or not, without using the @ operator to suppress the notice?

---

**EDIT**

Together with your first replies, I've been thinking about this and I'm getting the conclusion that inspecting get_defined_vars() is the only way to distinguish between a variable set to NULL and an unset variable. PHP seems to make little distinctions:

```
<?php

$exists_and_is_null = NULL;

// All these are TRUE

@var_dump(is_null($exists_and_is_null));
@var_dump(is_null($does_not_exist));

@var_dump($exists_and_is_null===NULL);
@var_dump($does_not_exist===NULL);

@var_dump(gettype($exists_and_is_null)=='NULL');
@var_dump(gettype($does_not_exist)=='NULL');

?>
```

Comment: Read this question a few times... what he's looking for is nonobvious and a lot more difficult than it first appears.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$result = array_key_exists('varname', get_defined_vars());
```

Comment: Probably not optimal but witty

Answer (score 0):

As you already found out, you cannot :

- rely on `isset`, as it return `false` for a variable that's `null`.
- use `$not_exists===null`, as it'll raise a notice.

But you could be able to use a combinaison of :

- [`get_defined_vars`](http://php.net/get_defined_vars) to get the list of existing variables, including those which are `null`,
- and [`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/array_key_exists) to find out if an entry exists in that list.

For instance :

```
$exists_and_null = null;
$exists_and_not_null = 10;

$defined_vars = get_defined_vars();

// true
var_dump(array_key_exists('exists_and_null', $defined_vars) 
    && $defined_vars['exists_and_null']===null);

// false
var_dump(array_key_exists('exists_and_not_null', $defined_vars) 
    && $defined_vars['exists_and_not_null']===null);

// false
var_dump(array_key_exists('not_exists', $defined_vars) 
    && $defined_vars['not_exists']===null);
```

A couple of notes :

- In the first case, the variable exists => there is an entry in the list returned by `get_defined_vars`, so the second part of the condition is evaluated

  - and both parts of the condition are `true`
- In the second case, the variable exists too, but is null

  - which means the first part of the condition is `true`, but the second one is `false`,
  - so the whole expression is `false`.
- In the third case, the variable doesn't exist,

  - which means the first part of the condition is `false`,
  - and the second part of the condition is not evaluated -- which means it doesn't raise a notice.

But note this is probably not that a good idea, if you care about performances : `isset` is a language construct, and is fast -- while calling `get_defined_vars` is probably much slower ^^

Comment: Excellent analysis. In practical terms, using @ looks like the best option.

Comment: Thanks :-) ;;; In practical terms, I would say there is generally no need to make a difference between *"doesn't exist"* and *"is null"* : in most cases, using `isset` should be just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I used a self created function to check this easily, keep in mind it will fire off a PHP warning (I only monitor E_ERROR when I develop).

```
    function isNullOrEmpty( $arg )
    {
        if ( !is_array( $arg ) )
        {
            $arg = array( $arg );
        }

        foreach ( $arg as $key => $value )
        {
            if( $value == null || trim($value) == "" )
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: This code could be cleaned up using proper  array_filter(), is_null, etc  but I'm not going to do that here without testing it, so I'll leave this here as a working example.

Answer (score 0):

I would argue here that any code requiring such a comparison would have gotten its semantics wrong; NULL **is** an unset value in a language that has no straightforward way of distinguishing between the two.

Comment: There is a difference between (e.g.) having an unset $phone_number (the user hasn't provided his number) and having a typo like $fone_number in your code. I find nothing wrong in handling both cases differently and IMHO it's pretty peculiar than PHP makes so little difference. Just look at SQL: a row with a NULL value is not the same as a non-existing row.

Comment: Of course there is. Yet, try to explain that to PHP. And don't even get me started on not being able to capture simple mistakes such as a typo (reading an unset variable) or passing the wrong number of parameters...

Comment: There - now the second sentence is stressed a lot more.

Answer (score -2):

```
if (isset($var) && (is_null($var)) {
    print "\$var is null";
}
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: This condition is FALSE when $var is NULL

Comment: using `print '$var is null'` removes the need to escape $ as single-quotes are not evaluated. It remain a string value